# Android Webview examping inside of scrollview / cannot scroll

Tags: android, webview, scrollview

Problem:

The scroll bar shows up for a SPLIT second then it's gone. I can change the `ScrollView`'s `height` to `100dp` and in the small little box I can scroll.

In the `Android Device Monitor` I can see that both elements are 1920 in height. It seems as though the webview is somehow pushing everything else to break their `match_parent` rules because they are acting more like `wrap_content`. What's going on here?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/speakerBioWebView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="1000dp"></WebView>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

## Solution

I noticed that `Android Studio` was voicing a faint warning about my setup. The warning showed as a faint red line underneath the `WebView`'s `layout_height` attribute. I changed the it to `match_parent` and took the outside `ScrollView` off.

This really was an error is oversight because the warning was not getting my attention at all. Make sure you look at all your compiler / IDE warnings to see if there are any helpful notices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want a scroll view around a WebView as
WebView has its own scroll bar.

Comment: That's what I had initially but it's the same issue. For some reason the Webview is blowing all the `match_parent` constraints.

Comment: If you take that minHeight off what happens

Comment: Same deal. I eventually figured out what was going on so I'm posting the solution to my question body but giving you the point since it ended with me scrapping the extra `ScrollView` anyway. Thanks for your help!